# There seems to be no limit to the number of downvotes on an Area 51 proposal's questions

Tags: bug, area-51, down-votes

Users can only upvote five questions per proposal on Area 51, as is well known. It is probably less well known that you don't have to have followed a proposal to upvote or even propose questions.

What I didn't know until I tested it today is that there does not seem to be any limit in the number of downvotes a user may inflict on a proposal, *even one they never committed to*. I just successfully made (and then reversed) seven downvotes on questions on a proposal I am not following.

Bulk downvoting would probably be picked up by the abuse detectors but it does seem like a loophole that would allow users to throw  sand in the wheels of a rival proposal to the o e they favor.

**EDIT** Please note that I am not referring to the per-day voting limits. The issue is that a user can only upvote five questions on a particular proposal, but can downvote all the the questions on that proposal. In the unlikely event there were more than 30 questions on a proposal, you could still downvote them all over several days. But you could only upvote five of them. This seems asymmetric.

Comment: This should probably be discussed on discussion.area51.stackexchange.com; Meta Stack Overflow is not anymore reported to be the meta for Area 51.

Comment: *throw sand in the wheels of a rival proposal to the one they favor* - This is an interesting statement.  There shouldn't be this kind of division on Area51.  Any examples?

Comment: @KevinVermeer none I could think of. Maybe I just am over-active in thinking about hypothetical and potentials.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ok I will ask it there. I just didn't see many questions about the *mechanics of the code* as opposed to the proposals themselves.

Comment: Questions that are not about the proposals should be tagged "area51-meta"; that is the tag used for questions about how Area 51 works, or feature requests that would change the code used on Area 51.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ok I have asked it over there. I hope I get to keep the Convention badge this question got me :-)